# Preventing Postfix backscattering

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, spam

I am having problems with the Postfix mail server being used for backscattering, I have tried the suggestions in the manual but nothing seems to work.  Does anyone know how we can reject any mail from entering the queue if the recipient doesn't match a local recipient rather than send bounce emails? I'm assuming it should be a fairly straight forward change in the configuration files. Just to note I am using Webmin/Virtualmin on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Set this because this causes local postfix to generate a 550 reject
# response to the SMTP server that initiated the connection
# rather than sending a bounce email to a likely bogus address
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

local_recipient_maps  = $virtual_mailbox_maps
```

Comment: I have added both of the above lines to main.cf configuration and yet this doesn't seem to solve the problem. My virtual_mailbox_maps is set to:`virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`

The map file is in the format:

    `username@domain.co.uk   username-domain.co.uk`